# pgadmin's insert data inserts empty row instead of values

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, pgadmin-4

I have a table of Employee which is like this

```
CREATE TABLE public."Employee"
(
    nid integer NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    fname character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    surname character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    date_of_birth date,
    speciality character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    doctor integer,
    CONSTRAINT "ID" PRIMARY KEY (nid)
);
```

And I've been trying to insert data into this table using the following code:

```
INSERT into "Employee" (fname,surname,nid,date_of_birth,speciality,doctor) values 
('Joseph','Ward',1,'12-10-1970','Orthodontics',1);
```

but when I try to view the data I inserted, Pgadmin shows an empty row to me. There are no Error messages shown just "INSERT 0 1"

Comment: "*when I try to view the data I inserted*" - how do you do that?

Comment: "*no Error messages shown just "INSERT 0 1"*" - that's the result of the insert query. It's a success message. It's not supposed to return any rows.

Comment: @Bergi i've tried both "SELECT * FROM "Employee" and viewing data from the pgadmin menu

Comment: It works for me. Do yourself a favor and work with [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), it will make your life easier.

Comment: I see two possible explanations: `search_path` or the unhelpful capitalization of `"Employee"`. Try `SELECT * FROM public."Employee";` With schema-qualification and double-quotes.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i really like to do that but my instructor insists on using only pgadmin (personally i think she doesn't know how...)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter if i don't use double-quotes, pgadmin gives me an error saying that it can't find the table.... (is it because i'm using an older version?) Otherwise i'd happily ditch the double-quotes.

Comment: Alright. Then look at comment from @ErwinBrandstetter . This `"INSERT 0 1"` says the `INSERT` happened. His comment gives you hints on how to find the table it actually ended up in. Do you have `psql` installed so you can look yourself before presenting an answer using `pgAdmin4`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Actually pgadmin includes a way to use psql: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/psql_tool.html

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I managed to fix it by restarting pgadmin twice and then running the insert query. The data can be seen in the table now.